# PostgreSQL:Difference of 2 rows as a new row

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have a table

```
Date,       employee    transaction  amount 
02-03-2015    e1          credit      400
02-03-2015    e1          debit        25
02-04-2015    e2          credit      600
02-04-2015    e2          debit        35
02-03-2015    e1          credit      400
02-03-2015    e1          debit       250
```

I want to create a temporary table as follows:

```
Date,       employee    transaction  amount 
02-03-2015    e1          credit      400
02-03-2015    e1          debit        25
02-03-2015    e1          NET_BAL     375
02-04-2015    e2          credit      600
02-04-2015    e2          debit        35
02-04-2015    e2          NET_BAL     565
02-04-2015    e1          credit      400
02-04-2015    e1          debit       250
02-04-2015    e1          NET_BAL     150
```

Could someone please help? I am new to SQL

Comment: mysql or postgreql ? is your no. of row fixed or may vary?

Comment: postgreSql. I don't want to modify the actual DB table.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you *CAN* do it, but not how you *should* do it. Even PostgreSQL (or several other RDBMS systems) can manipulate data to present denormalised and heterogeneous results, the presentation layer should be in charge of taking data from the server and break it down and format it nicely, not the database server.

```
with
  data (date, employee, transaction, amount) as (values
    ('02-03-2015', 'e1', 'credit', 400),
    ('02-03-2015', 'e1', 'debit', 25),
    ('02-04-2015', 'e2', 'credit', 600),
    ('02-04-2015', 'e2', 'debit', 35),
    ('02-04-2015', 'e1', 'credit', 400),
    ('02-04-2015', 'e1', 'debit', 250)),
  net as (
    select date, employee, 'NET_BAL'::text as transaction, sum(case when transaction = 'debit' then -1 else 1 end * amount) as amount
    from data
    group by date, employee)

select * from data
union
select * from net
order by date, employee, transaction
```